# Resize the image in Android (Gallery view)

Tags: android, xml

I am writing an application to customize the home application, where I am getting the images of all applications and displaying it in the gallery view. Now, what I want is to change the image size and the rotation angle of the images based on the right, left and center. I used the code

```
<Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery"
    android:background="#70000000"
    **android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"**
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:spacing="16dp"
/>
```

To change the size, but I am getting the default size of images for the default application, whereas for third-party images I am getting bigger images what size I am specifing.
I want all images to be equal of size.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the attributes below to `GridView` then it's for `GridView` only, not for the `GridView` items.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="60dip
```

If you want to fix the height and width of the `GridView` items, you can define a custom adapter for the `GridView` by taking a custom row layout. Define a custom row layout with 1 imageview with your desired height and width, and by using the same row xml layout, define a custom adapter for the `GridView` and use the same adapter to set inside the `GridView`.